# Repository pattern and change log implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, repository-pattern

I have API built with .net core 2, and I am trying to implement change log feature.

I have done basic part, but I am not sure if it's a best way for doing this.

Here is my EntityBaseRepository

```
public class EntityBaseRepository<T> : IEntityBaseRepository<T> where T : class, IFullAuditedEntity, new()
{
    private readonly ApplicationContext context;

    public EntityBaseRepository(ApplicationContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<T> items => context.Set<T>().AsEnumerable().OrderByDescending(m => m.Id);

    public virtual T this[int id] => context.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);

    public virtual T GetSingle(int id) => context.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

    public virtual T Add(T entity) => Operations(entity: entity, state: EntityState.Added);

    public virtual T Update(T entity) => Operations(entity: entity, state: EntityState.Modified);

    public virtual T Delete(T entity) => Operations(entity: entity, state: EntityState.Deleted);

    public virtual T Operations(T entity, EntityState state)
    {
        EntityEntry dbEntityEntry = context.Entry<T>(entity);

        if (state == EntityState.Added)
        {
            entity.CreationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            entity.CreationUserId = 1;

            context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Added;
        }
        else if (state == EntityState.Modified)
        {
            entity.LastModificationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            entity.LastModificationUserId = 1;

            var local = context.Set<T>().Local.FirstOrDefault(entry => entry.Id.Equals(entity.Id));
            if (local != null)
            {
                context.Entry(local).State = EntityState.Detached;
            }

            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        else if (state == EntityState.Deleted)
        {
            entity.DeletionFlag = true;
            entity.DeletionUserId = 1;
            entity.DeletionDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        return entity;
    }
```

Here is one of my controller.

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Item")]
public class ItemController : Controller
{
    private readonly IItemRepository repository;
    private readonly IChangeLogRepository changeLogRepository;
    private readonly IMapper mapper;

    public ItemController(IItemRepository repository, IChangeLogRepository _changeLogRepository, IMapper mapper)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.changeLogRepository = _changeLogRepository;
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody]ItemDto transactionItemDto)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var item = repository.Add(mapper.Map<ItemDto, Item>(source: transactionItemDto));
        repository.Commit();

        ChangeLog log = new ChangeLog()
        {
            Log = "New Item Added"
        };

        changeLogRepository.Add(log);
        changeLogRepository.Commit();

        return new OkObjectResult(mapper.Map<Item, ItemDto>(source: item));
    }
}
```

if you see in controller, I have added one item, and commited it, then I prepared log for that insertion, added and commited it.

Now, I have few questions, like

1. **I have to commit my transaction twice**, is there any way I can optimize it? I don't know if I can handle it on EntityBaseRepository or not.
2. I also want to check each property, if it gets changed or not. **I want to log that to if it's changed.** what would be the best way to handle it?

It would be great if anyone can help me with this. really appreciate. thanks.

Comment: Do not inject separate repos. Instead, create a container for all of them, the **Unit of Work**. Commit changes at the UoW level.

Comment: @WiktorZychla thanks for the suggestion, can you give me some kind of online example that best describe UoW in this cases. I mean some kind of reference.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Action filters for a changelog Like

```
using System;

public class TrackMyChange : IActionFilter
{
    private readonly string _chengeMessage;
    private readonly IChangeLogRepository _changeLogRepository;
    public TrackMyChange(string changeMessage,IChangeLogRepository changeLogRepository)
    {
        this._changeLogRepository = changeLogRepository;
        this._chengeMessage = chengeMessage;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
    // Do something before the action executes.
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        // Do something after the action executes.
        ChangeLog log = new ChangeLog()
        {Log = this._chengeMessage};
        changeLogRepository.Add(log);
        changeLogRepository.Commit();
    }
}
```

In your controller, you can use it before actions you want to log like

```
[TrackMyChange("Your change log here")]
public IActionResult Post()
{
}
```

---

**Reference :**
[Action Filter Attributes in .NET core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Answer (score 1):

1. DbContext is shared between multiple repositories within the same HTTP request scope. You won't need UoW. Just try use one Commit() and see if all changes are saved in one transaction.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/infrastructure-persistence-layer-implemenation-entity-framework-core

2. Use **yourDbContext.Entry(your_entity_obj).State** to get entity state. Don't log if its state is **EntityState.Unchanged**.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entitystate?view=efcore-2.1